# Restlet Rest server on android

Tags: android, restlet, restlet-2.0

I want to host a simple rest server on an android phone to get remote access to some data.
I followed the descriptions on the restlet website but I cant even get a simple example running.

I downloaded the android restlet package and added the org.restlet.jar as dependency.

In my `onCreate` method of the activity I have added these lines to start a simple server component.

```
Component serverComponent = new Component();
serverComponent.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 80);  
final Router router = new Router(serverComponent.getContext().createChildContext());  
router.attach("/gamedata", GameDataResourceServer.class);  
serverComponent.getDefaultHost().attach(router);  
serverComponent.start();
```

The last call throws an Exception:

> 05-20 11:06:14.040  29947-29947/com.example.restserver
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.restserver, PID: 29947
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer
>               at org.restlet.engine.connector.HttpServerHelper.start(HttpServerHelper.java:68)
>   ...

Why does the restlet framework tries to use the httpserver from java. This in not part of the android framework as I think.

P.S.: I figured out, that this issue only appears since restlet 2.2. The 2.1 branch works for me.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is not a forum! Read [faq]. I am stressing this because you seem to have solved your own problem, so what you should do is post an answer to your question instead of having edited your question to include a small PS at the end.

Comment: Could you enter a GitHub issue in Restlet?

Answer (score 1):

The Android edition of Restlet shouldn't offer this internal HTTP server based on com.sun.net as this class isn't available on Android, only on Java SE/EE.

The previous internal HTTP server that is used in version 2.1 has been moved to the org.restlet.ext.nio extension. You can still use it in version 2.2 if you do the proper declaration.