# Restlet in JBOSS: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler ClassNotFound Exception on Java Embedded Runtime Environment

Tags: jboss, restlet

I have an application using Restlet EE 2.2 which runs fine in Tomcat 7 but fails in JBOSS 6.2 (see stack trace below). I realise from the trace that it is not finding the HTTP stack classes but I have very little familiarity with JBOSS.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179243/com-sun-net-httpserver-httphandler-classnotfound-exception-on-java-embedded-runt/25187460#25187460) that was asked today albeit not about JBOSS.
Thanks in advance!

```
09:45:13,041 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/rest].[greeting]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000235: Allocate exception for servlet greeting: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler from [Module "deployment.rest.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerDefaultConnectors(Engine.java:734) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:553) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:386) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:308) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:297) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:206) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getLogger(Engine.java:262) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.Context.<init>(Context.java:167) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.Context.<init>(Context.java:139) [org.restlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createComponent(ServerServlet.java:429) [org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getComponent(ServerServlet.java:843) [org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar:]
    at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.init(ServerServlet.java:961) [org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:950) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:151) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ACT-2069) jira page, you need to update you module.xml file.

Add the following

```
<path name="com/sun/net/httpserver"/>
```

To the module.xml file found in:

```
modules\system\layers\base\sun\jdk\main
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JBoss7.1.1 Final adding `<path name="com/sun/net/httpserver"/>` to    modules\sun\jdk\main resolved the issue.