# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when calling an api

Tags: java

I am working on an existing application written in Java 7.

I have the following utility method:

```
private static String callAuth(String endpointUrl, String userName, String password) {
    //System.out.println(endpointUrl);
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("username", userName);
        jo.put("password", password);
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(endpointUrl);
        Representation response = cr.post(new JsonRepresentation(jo), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String jsonString = response.getText();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AuthenticationResponse.class);
        System.out.println(authenticationResponse.getJwt());
        return authenticationResponse.getJwt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I call this method via a main, it works, i.e. it successfully calls the the external api.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jwtToken = callAuth(authUrl, "richardmarais", "d18dc3184bdcb2bffdeae7ac9409b3701d9f2a3ade45994669458aea078114fcc2c4f83b85ed440358a9165e23167b9f");
}
```

However, if I start the application (which is a Struts application that runs on a JBoss server),  and call the method, on a breakpoint I can see that on this line:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(endpointUrl);
```

There is the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.restlet.data.Method
```

However, it does not get caught in the Catch block of the utility method.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Rather up the chain, in another class there's a catch block, with the following error.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
```

cause:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.restlet.data.Method
```

So it appears like the application is not seeing the class it's working on or something. Is the restlet dependencies out of scope or something? They are visible when running from the `main` method, but not from within the application.

POM

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.restlet.jee/org.restlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am pretty confused, and if anyone could provide some direction, I would appreciate it.

Entire Stack Trace:

```
14:08:20,920 SEVERE [com.travellinck.travelIT.requisition.action.SelectQuotesAction] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1) There was an error trying to auto approve a trip. Unexpected Error
14:08:23,242 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1) javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
14:08:23,243 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:157)
14:08:23,244 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:213)
14:08:23,245 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:284)
14:08:23,245 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:182)
14:08:23,246 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,247 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
14:08:23,248 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,249 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
14:08:23,249 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:146)
14:08:23,250 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,252 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
14:08:23,253 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:76)
14:08:23,254 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.approval.ApprovalRequestSubmissionService$$$view37.retrieveEvaluatorsList(Unknown Source)
14:08:23,255 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:08:23,256 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:08:23,257 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:08:23,258 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:08:23,259 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
14:08:23,259 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
14:08:23,260 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
14:08:23,261 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
14:08:23,261 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
14:08:23,262 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:62)
14:08:23,263 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
14:08:23,264 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.approval.autoselection.ApprovalRequestSubmissionService$-1239349679$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.retrieveEvaluatorsList(ApprovalRequestSubmissionService$-1239349679$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
14:08:23,265 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.travelIT.requisition.action.SelectQuotesAction.executeSpecificTask(SelectQuotesAction.java:370)
14:08:23,266 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at corptravweb.actions.base.BaseBookingPortalAction.execute(BaseBookingPortalAction.java:98)
14:08:23,266 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:479)
14:08:23,267 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:237)
14:08:23,268 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1962)
14:08:23,269 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:459)
14:08:23,270 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
14:08:23,271 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
14:08:23,271 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
14:08:23,272 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,273 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67)
14:08:23,274 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,275 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,275 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at application.configuration.cache.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:28)
14:08:23,276 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at application.configuration.cache.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:20)
14:08:23,277 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,277 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,278 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at application.configuration.logging.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:61)
14:08:23,280 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,280 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,281 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.protection.InputProtectionFilter.doFilter(InputProtectionFilter.java:30)
14:08:23,282 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,283 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,284 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.travelIT.admin.sessiontracker.LoggedInUsersFilter.doFilter(LoggedInUsersFilter.java:67)
14:08:23,286 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,287 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,288 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.notes.filter.UpdateNotesFilter.doFilter(UpdateNotesFilter.java:75)
14:08:23,289 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,290 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,291 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:42)
14:08:23,292 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,294 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,294 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at application.configuration.compression.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:29)
14:08:23,295 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,296 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,297 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at corptravweb.security.TLJaasAdaptorFilter.doFilter(TLJaasAdaptorFilter.java:31)
14:08:23,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
14:08:23,299 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
14:08:23,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
14:08:23,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
14:08:23,302 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139)
14:08:23,303 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:388)
14:08:23,304 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57)
14:08:23,305 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:49)
14:08:23,306 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154)
14:08:23,306 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
14:08:23,307 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
14:08:23,308 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
14:08:23,308 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
14:08:23,309 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667)
14:08:23,310 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952)
14:08:23,310 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14:08:23,311 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler
14:08:23,312 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerDefaultConnectors(Engine.java:730)
14:08:23,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:546)
14:08:23,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:379)
14:08:23,314 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:301)
14:08:23,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:290)
14:08:23,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:199)
14:08:23,316 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:337)
14:08:23,317 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:396)
14:08:23,317 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:361)
14:08:23,318 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:48)
14:08:23,319 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:396)
14:08:23,320 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.approval.helpers.ApprovalUtilityRestService.callAuth(ApprovalUtilityRestService.java:62)
14:08:23,320 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.approval.helpers.ApprovalUtilityRestService.sendApprovalRequest(ApprovalUtilityRestService.java:38)
14:08:23,321 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.approval.autoselection.ApprovalAutoSelectionRequestSubmissionImpl.submitApprovalRequest(ApprovalAutoSelectionRequestSubmissionImpl.java:323)
14:08:23,322 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at com.travellinck.approval.autoselection.ApprovalAutoSelectionRequestSubmissionImpl.retrieveEvaluatorsList(ApprovalAutoSelectionRequestSubmissionImpl.java:190)
14:08:23,323 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:08:23,323 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:08:23,324 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:08:23,325 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:08:23,325 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
14:08:23,326 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,327 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:370)
14:08:23,327 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:122)
14:08:23,328 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:130)
14:08:23,329 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,329 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
14:08:23,330 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,331 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:45)
14:08:23,331 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,332 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:44)
14:08:23,333 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,334 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
14:08:23,335 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,336 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
14:08:23,338 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,339 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
14:08:23,340 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:202)
14:08:23,340 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,341 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:50)
14:08:23,342 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:287)
14:08:23,342 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.session.SessionInvocationContextInterceptor$CustomSessionInvocationContext.proceed(SessionInvocationContextInterceptor.java:126)
14:08:23,343 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:211)
14:08:23,344 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  ... 75 more
14:08:23,345 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler from [Module "deployment.corporateEAR-3.10.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
14:08:23,345 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
14:08:23,346 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
14:08:23,347 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
14:08:23,347 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
14:08:23,348 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
14:08:23,349 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-1)  ... 117 more
```

Comment: Looks like this might be the reason, but I am not sure why:  `ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler`

Comment: Here is the same error, so I will try what they suggest.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179243/com-sun-net-httpserver-httphandler-classnotfound-exception-on-java-embedded-runt

Comment: Adding these fixed the issue: `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>http</artifactId>
        <version>20070405</version>
    </dependency>`.   However, there is now a next issue:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException$Reference`.